# Getting null at setting actionBar icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawable

I've got problem with my actionBar. Tryin' to set an icon but still getting null :/ Here's code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#51717e")));

    }
```

Ofc I've got logo in my drawable folder. Both lines are incorrect - Icon and Background color. Help :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Actionbar null because the Theme don't have ActionBar.
Try to set the background and icon in your `styles.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call getSupportActionBar() on an ActionBarActivity. Do not call getActionBar() -- that is not available on older devices, and for the new r21 edition of appcompat-v7, I would expect it to return null all the time, as the new ActionBarActivity disables and replaces the system action bar.and surround these two line in try catch like:

```
try{
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
 getSupportActionBar() .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#51717e")));
 }catch(NullPointerException e)
 {
 e.printstacktrace();
 }
```

Comment: please provide your theme and extended Activity and share logcat

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

Comment: Null ... Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Do you extends Activity ?